# Angular 7: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, angular7

There is a data toggle drop down which is populated from http request.

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <input #searchInput class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" id="dropdown-input" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off"
     (input)="handleChange(searchInput.value)"
     data-toggle="dropdown">

<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
<ng-template [ngIf]="isAsync">
  <li class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let d of asyncData$ | async">{{valueAttribute ? d[valueAttribute] : d }}</li>
</ng-template>
```

I use Angular **async** pipe as in above code. And I tried below.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.asyncData$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
    // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
    debounceTime(300),

    // ignore new term if same as previous term
    distinctUntilChanged(),

    // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
    switchMap((term: string) => this.retrieveData(term)),
);
```

}

```
retrieveData(term: string) {
 let options: any = {};
 if (this.queryParamName) {
   options.params = {};
   options.params[this.queryParamName] = term;
 }
 return this.http.get(this.url, options);
```

}

Http call returns success response but following error occurs.

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the data in `asyncData$` ? This error means that the given value is not an array

Comment: Might be asyncData$ is an object not the Array. That's the case of this error. So check it.

Comment: Also check whether the intended array is assigned to a property in the returned json. In that case you need to return the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the values emitted by `asyncData$` are objects, not arrays. You can convert them into arrays using `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`.

You can also use the built-in keyvalue pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of asyncData$ | async | keyvalue">
  {{ d.key }} {{ d.value }}
</div>
```